# WebView.capturePicture failing with url parameters

Tags: android

[Android Newbie alert]

I need to capture the contents of a WebView in a BitMap and I've run into a strange problem. My approach is to register a WebViewClient with the WebView, and in *onPageFinished* I call *capturePicture*. With a simple URL (e.g. http://www.yahoo.com), it works fine. In other cases, capturePicture returns a Picture with height and width values = 0. The page loads fine, either way. The actual url I have to use has quite a few url parameters and I initially thought having any parameters was the problem, but that's not the case. Here's a few sample urls with comments indicating whether it works or not:

1. w.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"); //yes
2. w.loadUrl("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=android"); // usually not???
3. w.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com?foo=bar"); // nope
4. w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); // yep
5. w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com?q=android"); // yep
6. w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com?foo=bar"); // yes

The second case is particularly frustrating as it appears to not work. However, if I run the test app with #5 first, then switching the url to #2 and running it then works.

Here's a snippet of an actual simplified test I created:

> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> ```

```
    w = new WebView(this);
    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
            Picture picture = webview.capturePicture();

            Log.d("Height", "" + picture.getHeight());
            Log.d("Width", "" + picture.getWidth());
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), picture
                    .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            picture.draw(c);
        }
    });

    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    setContentView(w);

    //w.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com"); //yes
    w.loadUrl("http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=android"); // usually not???
    //w.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com?foo=bar"); // nope
    //w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); // yep
    //w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com?q=android"); // yep
    //w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com?foo=bar"); // yes
}
```

Has anyone run into this issue? Hopefully I'm just being an idiot and there's a simple solution or workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just visited the documentation page again.
[here][1]

*"Notify the host application that a page has finished loading. This method is called only for main frame. When onPageFinished() is called, the rendering picture may **not** be updated yet. To get the notification for the new Picture, **use onNewPicture(WebView, Picture)**."*

Used Picture Listener, I tried with your sample and it works.
Hope this helps.

I just added below code to your example and removed WebViewClient

```
 w.setPictureListener(new PictureListener(){

    public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onNewPicture- Height"+ picture.getHeight());
            Log.d(TAG, "onNewPicture- Width"+ picture.getWidth());
        }

    });
```

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. However, I'm unable to get onNewPicture to be triggered. From the API description, I would think that I still have to listen for onPageFinished to begin the capturePicture and then use onNewPicture to listen for that to complete, but I must not we setting up the listener correctly. If I'm supposed to use onNewPicture instead of onPageFinished, I still don't ever see it getting called. Could you provide a bit more detail on how you got it to work?

Comment: Ah, I was making things much too complicated by not realizing that the Picture comes "free". Thanks for your help.